# Converting a nested for-loop for string search for optimization in R

Tags: r, string, for-loop, optimization, text

I am relatively new to R. I have written the following code. However, because it uses a for-loop, it is slow. I am not too familiar with packages that will convert this for-loop into a more efficient solution (`apply` functions?).

What my code does is this: it is trying to extract country names from a variable based on another dataframe that has all countries.

For instance, this is what `data` looks like:

```
country       Institution
              edmonton general hospital
              ontario, canada
              miyazaki, japan
              department of head
```

this is what `countries` looks like

```
Name       Code
algeria    dz
canada     ca
japan      jp
kenya      ke

# string match the countries
for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  for (j in 1:nrow(countries))
  {
    data$country[i] <- ifelse(str_detect(string = data$Institution[i], pattern = paste0("\\b", countries$Name[j], "\\b")), countries$Name[j], data$country[i])
  }
}
```

The above code runs so that it changes `data` so it looks like this:

```
country       Institution
              edmonton general hospital
canada        ontario, canada
japan         miyazaki, japan
              department of head
```

How can I convert my for-loop to preserve the same function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a one-liner with `str_extract`. We'll paste the country names together with word boundaries and concatenate them with a regex `|` or operator.

```
library(stringr)
data$country = str_extract(data$Institution, paste0(
  "\\b", country$Name, "\\b", collapse = "|"
))
data
#                 Institution country
# 1 edmonton general hospital    <NA>
# 2           ontario, canada  canada
# 3           miyazaki, japan   japan
# 4        department of head    <NA>
```

---

Using this data:

```
country <- read.table(text = "  Name       Code
                            algeria    dz
                            canada     ca
                            japan      jp
                            kenya      ke",
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

data <- data.frame(Institution = c("edmonton general hospital",   
  "ontario, canada",
  "miyazaki, japan",
  "department of head"))
```

Comment: i want an output of 4 lines...even though edmonton general hospital and department of head have no country affiliation, i need to have them in separate lines with their country being ""

Comment: I just misunderstood your input (I assumed Denis had it correct). See updates.

Comment: this was beautiful. I love it so much! thank you for such a simple and elegant answer, Gregor!

Comment: your answer gave me so much excitement because I didn't realize how efficient the capabilities of `stringr` are...thanks for lighting up the fire in me ahah!

Comment: I have a very similar, related question. what if in `data$Institution` I have `countries$Code` that I need to map out to `countries$Name`? for ex, `data$Institution[1] = ontario, ca` and I want its `data$country[1] = canada` based on the datasets I have already.

Comment: Should work about the same. `str_extract` the country code (the word boundaries `\\b` will be more important this time!) then join you your look-up table. Give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

The data:

```
countries <- setDT(read.table(text = "  Name       Code
                            algeria    dz
                            canada     ca
                            japan      jp
                            kenya      ke",
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE))



data <- setDT(list(country = array(dim = 2),      Institution =
                 c("edmonton general hospital  ontario, canada",
"miyazaki, japan department of head")))
```

I use data.table for syntax convenience, but you can surely do otherwise, the main idea is to use just one loop and grepl

```
data[,country := as.character(country)]
for( x in unique(countries$Name)){data[grepl(x,data$Institution),country := x]}

> data
   country                                Institution
1:  canada edmonton general hospital  ontario, canada
2:   japan         miyazaki, japan department of head
```

You could add the tolower function to avoid cases problems `grepl(tolower(x),tolower(data$Institution))`

Comment: is there a way to avoid any for-loop? also, in your answer, you made the dataframe `country` instead of `countries`, so I am not sure when in your code you are referring to the dataframe country vs the data$country...could you update your answer to match my dataframe names from the question?